# Axis PDF Export Artifact

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf-generation

Why is the PDF export of this matplotlib plot incorrect with the following errors. It looks fine

- minor axis being over the plot surroundings?
- Plotted lines going below the minor/major grid?

```py
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = 'Arev Sans'        
mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 12                  
mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [6.71, 6.71/1.6180]
mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 1.5
mpl.rcParams['grid.color'] = '#cccccc'
mpl.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True
mpl.rcParams['grid.linewidth'] = 0.8
mpl.rcParams['grid.linestyle'] = '-'
mpl.rcParams['axes.grid.which'] = 'major'
mpl.rcParams['xtick.minor.visible'] = True
mpl.rcParams['ytick.minor.visible'] = True
mpl.rcParams['figure.edgecolor'] = 'none'
mpl.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'none'
mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = mpl.cycler(color=['#024096', '#56cffc', '#00b09c', '#EE7733', '#CC3311', '#EE3377', '#BBBBBB'])
plt.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 1.5



plt.figure(1)
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = np.linspace(0,1,100)
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(which='minor', color='#999999', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.2)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y+0.1)
plt.plot(x,y+0.2)
plt.plot(x,y+0.3)
plt.plot(x,y+0.4)
plt.plot(x,y+0.5)
plt.savefig('destination_path.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

[image]

It looks fine on the qt based viewer

[image]